# VBA msoFileDialogOpen declare filename as Path

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, excel-2010

I am trying to use msoFileDialogOpen to retrieve the corresponding filename the user selected. Here is my clumsy code so far:

```
Public Sub Function3_FileExplorer()
'   Start File Explorer to select file containing data (simple GUI, much easier than coding vFileName)
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show Then
        Dim file As Variant
        For Each file In .SelectedItems
            .SelectedItems Path
    End If
End With
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error detected" & vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & Err.Line
    Err.Description , vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number

End Sub
```

When I run this program I get the error message:

> Compile error:
>
> Invalid use of property

I think using property .SelectedItems is the right thing to do here but I'm not sure how to take that filename and store it as a variant.

EDIT: the revised code (does this do what I want it to do?)

```
Public Sub Function3_FileExplorer()
Dim file As Variant
'   Start File Explorer to select file containing data (simple GUI, much easier than coding vFileName)
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show Then
        file = .SelectedItems(1)
        Path = file
    End If
End With
MsgBox file

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error detected" & vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & _
       Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What is `.SelectedItems Path` supposed to do? This will give `Path` as a parameter to a function call of `.SelectedItems`, which is no function but a property.

Comment: @EngJon you have confused me completely (;

Comment: Sorry for that. Follow Rory's answer, it gives you a solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically what you want (it's not clear what you really want to do with the file name):

```
Public Sub Function3_FileExplorer()
    Dim file          As Variant
'   Start File Explorer to select file containing data (simple GUI, much easier than coding vFileName)
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show Then
            file = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox file

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error detected" & vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & _
           Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number

End Sub
```

Comment: I tweaked your code, can you check my new block of code at top where the question is to see if I did it right? Thanks!

Comment: Don't know - what is `Path`?

Comment: another variable in  my project.

Comment: Looks OK, but I don't know why you're asking us whether it does what you want - surely you can tell? :)